# Oracle: sort the results of a regexp_like expression

Tags: oracle, regexp-like

I have a table containing the following values:

```
Org    Role  
----   ---------  
XX     Role2  
XXX    Role3  
XXXX   Role4    
null   RoleDefault
```

I need a query accepting a parameter that would give me the best match using a regexp_like in the where condition.
For example with :userOrg = XXX
a query like this
   **select *
   from table
   where regex_like(:userOrg,Org**)

would return

```
Role2  
Role3
```

I would like to get something like this

```
Role3 1  
Role2 2
```

in order to pick XXX as the best match.

We the like operator this is feasible.
But we want to switch to regexp_like to use regular expression.
Is this possible?
Thank you

Comment: Getting a match is of course possible.  Getting a _best_ match implies that you intend to rank all terms based on some similarity measurement.  What is that measurement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind is `UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY` used with `RANK()`, but it may not yield the same result you are expecting, say 2 for Role2.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c0c7/8)

**Query**:

```
select org,role,
 rank() OVER ( ORDER BY UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY( ORG,'XXX') desc ) as matched
from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c0c7/8/0)**:

```
|    ORG |        ROLE | MATCHED |
|--------|-------------|---------|
|    XXX |       Role3 |       1 |
|   XXXX |       Role4 |       2 |
|     XX |       Role2 |       3 |
| (null) | RoleDefault |       4 |
```